# Python + Celery: Prevent duplicate task execution

Tags: python, celery

How can I prevent the execution of two or more identical tasks at the same time?

For example: if I have a task called `do_stuff` and a program calling it, it should only get executed if there is no other instance of `do_stuff` that is currently running.

Comment: There are 2 ways. You can either create a lock to prevent multiple executions http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html or use the following module https://github.com/cameronmaske/celery-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [DOCS](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time):

> You can accomplish this by using a lock.

With this caveat:

> In order for this to work correctly you need to be using a cache backend where the .add operation is atomic. memcached is known to work well for this purpose.